# Conda Install command failing

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am using conda 4.6.11 and below is the requirements file that I am using

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
boto3=1.16.16=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyarrow=0.13.0=py37h0978efd_0
s3fs=0.4.2=py_0
findspark=1.3.0=py_1
```

On running

```
conda install -c conda-forge --yes --file requirements.txt
```

I get the below error

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: / *** picosat: out of memory in 'resize'
Aborted
```

Any suggestions on what could be breaking the installation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this resolved issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9067) documenting the same error, updating your Conda will resolve the issue:

```
conda update -n base conda
```

Answer (score 0):

solved me issue of conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3